# I am getting perfect view in graphical layout but in avd it's not looking good. Is there any solution?

Tags: android

I am getting proper view in my graphical layout but when I see the output in avd it's not covering the whole screen. How can I make it proper? Can anyone help me.
Thanks in advance.

My landscape layout-land\main.xml

```
<AbsoluteLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">
       <TableLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:weightSum="1.0" 
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                         android:gravity="center"
                     >

                        <TableRow
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView1"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:text="@string/Msg" />
                        </TableRow>

                <TableRow
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/editText1"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1" 
                        android:singleLine="true"/>
                </TableRow>

                    <TableRow
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView1"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:text="@string/hint" />
                    </TableRow>
                    <TableRow
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/txt_hint"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1" 
                        android:singleLine="true"
                       />
                    </TableRow>

                    <TableRow
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="center_horizontal" >
                      <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:orientation="horizontal"
                            android:weightSum="1.0">
                              <Button
                              android:id="@+id/btn_encry"                                                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                              android:layout_weight="0.3"
                              android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                              android:layout_marginLeft="75dp"
                              android:text="@string/EncryButton" /></LinearLayout>
                    </TableRow>

                    </TableLayout>
        </AbsoluteLayout>
```

Comment: Is this your complete layout ? Please your Screenshot how it looks in device?

Comment: Using only 4-5 views how do you expect to cover whole screen?

Comment: @GrIsHu I'm new to android.will u please explain it briefly.

Comment: What do you want to understand ? Let me know What do you mean by `but when i see the output in avd its not covering the whole screen.how can i make it proper?`

Comment: when i see the xml page in graphical layout it covers the whole screen but in emulator it is not covering the whole screen

Comment: As i said post a screenshot.

Comment: @GrIsHu sorry i need 10 reputations to post an image :(

Comment: You can post the link of your image by uploading it online. @Ramya

Comment: @Ramya Did you fix this issue

Comment: @No_Rulz Ya i got it by changing the target API level.I'm not sure this as a correct solution.

Comment: @Ramya hmmm fine.. From my suggestion don't use Absolute layout, it may cause a pbm lot and also it deprecated :)